# Django REST framework. APITestCase. How test views which response for download data to csv

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have views like:

```
class StudentAPIPerformanceReport(
    generics.RetrieveAPIView,
):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer(response)
        for student in Student.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']):
            assigned_courses = CourseParticipant.objects.filter(student=student)
            completed_courses = assigned_courses.filter(completed=True)

            headings = (
                "student full Name",
                "number of assigned courses to student",
                "number of completed courses by student"
            )
            rows = (
                student.full_name,
                assigned_courses.count(),
                completed_courses.count()
            )

            writer.writerow(headings)
            writer.writerow(rows)

        return response
```

Urls:

```
    path(
    'student/report/<int:pk>/',
    StudentAPIPerformanceReport.as_view(),
    name='student_performance'
)
```

And test for it view:

```
class StudentAPIPerformanceReportTestCase(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.student_obj = Student.objects.create(
        first_name='test',
        last_name='student',
        email='test_student@gmail.com',
    )
    self.course_obj = Course.objects.create(
        name='test',
    )
    student_obj = CourseParticipant.objects.create(
        course_id=self.course_obj.pk,
        student_id=self.student_obj.pk,
    )

def test_student_unassigned_from_course(self):
    data_id = self.student_obj.pk
    rud_url = api_reverse('student:student_performance', kwargs={'pk': data_id})

    get_response = self.client.get(rud_url, data_id)
    self.assertEqual(get_response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But i have Traceback:

> Error
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/project/test_task/student/tests.py", line 120, in test_student_unassigned_from_course
>       get_response = self.client.get(rud_url, data_id)
>     File "/home/project/test_task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 292, in get
>       response = super(APIClient, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
>     File "/home/project/test_task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 199, in get
>       'QUERY_STRING': urlencode(data or {}, doseq=True),
>     File "/home/project/test_task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/http.py", line 93, in urlencode
>       for key, value in query:
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Api which i wont to test just make some csv file in format:

```
test student,1,0
```

How i can test it? I will be grateful for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is from the way you call `self.client.get`.

---

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

is about the second parameter that you are passing in this particular line:

```
get_response = self.client.get(rud_url, data_id)
# ______________________________________^
```

`data_id` itself is the student object's primary key, which is a simple integer id.

If you look closer at the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get), the second parameter of `get()` is data, which is **a dictionary**, not **an integer**. That's why it tries to iterate this parameter, but it *is not iterable*.

Since you've already attached your primary key in the url (in the `reverse()`), there is no need to attach it as a query parameter of the GET request performed by `self.client.get()`.

---

Once you remove `data_id` from the `get()` function call

```
get_response = self.client.get(rud_url)
```

it should work and you will successfully get the CSV file in the response, which you can test further.

Comment: Yes. When i removed 'data_id' from get_response = self.client.get(rud_url, data_id) it works and i get CSV. Thank you. Need read documentation more attentively. :)